VBA Code to automatically @mention someone in Excel Online
I am trying to create an excel code that will automatically mention a user and assign the task to them in Excel Online by adding a threaded comment. ChatGPT is giving me only code that adds a note, but the note doesn't have the same functionality as a threaded comment and can not tag a user / assign the task and send an email to them. For reference, see below the code from CGPT. Appreciate any help.
Sub AddCommentAndAssignTask()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim commentText As String
    Dim person As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim column As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Q&A") ' Change "Q&A" to your sheet name
    
    startRow = 7
    column = 12 ' Column L
    
    ' Find the last used row in column L
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each cell in column L from L7 to the last used row
    For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, column), ws.Cells(lastRow, column))
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            person = cell.Value
            commentText = "Assigned to: @" & person
            
            ' Add or modify the comment (note)
            If Not cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
                cell.Comment.Delete
            End If
            cell.AddComment commentText
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

ChatGPT but it is not able to give me the threaded comment, only the yellow "note"

Have you checked for similar questions on here?

Yes obviously, didn't work..

Range.AddCommentThreaded. One often helpful approach is to use the macro recorder to get you started. I'm not sure if "assign the task to them in Excel Online" will work though.

The issue is I don't know how to code / use VBA. I am 100% relying on chatgpt / forums. It doesn't necessarily need to assign the task as well, just tag them with the @
